# Getting the last User Entry in db with Doctrine when there are multiple rows for each user

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to get the last entry made in the database for the user in order to make calculations with the data in my program. Using the last() method does not work in this instance as last() will return a null value. Please read on and I'll explain further. Check out my controller here:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("user/PyramidPressOverHead", name="user_PyramidPressOverHead")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 */
public function pyramidPressOverHead(Request $request)
{
    $exercisestats = $this->getExerciseStatsByCurrentUser();
    $newwtpoh15 = $this->getExerciseWeightAndReps('poh1',15);
    $newwtpoh12 = $this->getExerciseWeightAndReps('poh2',12);
    $newwtpoh10 = $this->getExerciseWeightAndReps('poh3',10);
    $newwtpoh8 = $this->getExerciseWeightAndReps('poh4',8);
    $newwtpoh6 = $this->getExerciseWeightAndReps('poh5',6);

    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\PressOverHeadStatsType', $exercisestats);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $exercisestats->setUserId($this->getUser());
        $exercisestats->setTimestamp(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $em->persist($exercisestats);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_PyramidTricepsExtension');
    }

    return $this->render('user/PyramidPressOverHead.html.twig', array(
        'exercisestats' => $exercisestats,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'poh15' => $newwtpoh15, 'poh12' => $newwtpoh12, 'poh10' => $newwtpoh10,
        'poh8' => $newwtpoh8, 'poh6' => $newwtpoh6,
    ));
}
```

The controller doesn't really show you what is commited. The twig gives you more here:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<head>


    {% block stylesheets %}<link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" 
    rel="stylesheet" media="screen">{% endblock %}
    </head>
<body background="{{ asset('sport-1244925_1920.jpg') }}">

{{ form_start(form, { 'style': 'horizontal', 'col_size': 'xs' }) }}
<h1>Press Over Head</h1>
<h3>Your Weight for Set One is {{ poh15 }}</h3>
{{ form_row(form.press_over_head_1_reps) }}
{{ form_row(form.press_over_head_1_weight) }}
<h3>Your Weight for Set two is {{ poh12 }}</h3>
{{ form_row(form.press_over_head_2_reps) }}
{{ form_row(form.press_over_head_2_weight) }}
<h3>Your Weight for Set three is {{ poh10 }}</h3>
{{ form_row(form.press_over_head_3_reps) }}
{{ form_row(form.press_over_head_3_weight) }}
<h3>Your Weight for Set four is {{ poh8 }}</h3>
{{ form_row(form.press_over_head_4_reps) }}
{{ form_row(form.press_over_head_4_weight) }}
<h3>Your Weight for Set five is {{ poh6 }}</h3>
{{ form_row(form.press_over_head_5_reps) }}
{{ form_row(form.press_over_head_5_weight) }}

<h2>Before hitting the submit button, please check over all of your
numbers to ensure they are accurate.</h2>
{{ form_row(form.submit) }}


{% endblock %}
```

The person enters in how many reps they did as well as the weight for each exercise. When they hit the submit button, it commits to the db. The table has about 40 columns in it. It is populated with the user's stats one exercise at a time. When one exercise is committed, those columns which have no data in them are made null when the commit is done. Here's a snippet of my entity:

```
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="press_over_head_1_reps", type="smallint", length=6,
 *     nullable=true)
 */
private $press_over_head_1_reps;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="press_over_head_1_weight", type="smallint", length=6,
 *     nullable=true)
 */
private $press_over_head_1_weight;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="press_over_head_2_reps", type="smallint", length=6,
 *     nullable=true)
 */
private $press_over_head_2_reps;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="press_over_head_2_weight", type="smallint", length=6,
 *     nullable=true)
 */
private $press_over_head_2_weight;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="press_over_head_3_reps", type="smallint", length=6,
 *     nullable=true)
 */
private $press_over_head_3_reps;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="press_over_head_3_weight", type="smallint", length=6,
 *     nullable=true)
 */
private $press_over_head_3_weight;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="press_over_head_4_reps", type="smallint", length=6,
 *     nullable=true)
 */
private $press_over_head_4_reps;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="press_over_head_4_weight", type="smallint", length=6,
 *     nullable=true)
 */
private $press_over_head_4_weight;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="press_over_head_5_reps", type="smallint", length=6,
 *     nullable=true)
 */
private $press_over_head_5_reps;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="press_over_head_5_weight", type="smallint", length=6,
 *     nullable=true)
 */
private $press_over_head_5_weight;
```

I have everything set in the entity to nullable=true because if a commit is done without nullable=true in the fields that don't get data yet, errors are thrown.

The program tracks the person's statistics, so each time they work out, there is a new row for that workout day. So, in trying to use this in my  controller:

```
$this->getUser()->getExerciseStats()->last()->getPressOverHead2Reps();
```

it returns null. Press Over Head is the 2nd exercise in the routine. Since the first exercise has been submitted, it rendered all blank fields with null, hence every exercise after the first one returns null, but I need the last actual entry in the db to make calculations and populate the twig.

Here's my User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ExerciseStats", 
mappedBy="user_id")
 */
private $exerciseStats;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getExerciseStats()
{
    return $this->exerciseStats;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how I could get the data for that last row entered by the user in the db?

Let me know if anyone needs any clarification. Thanks for taking the time to check this out.

Comment: Probably going to need more info, as i dont really get where this is going. Can you show what is going on in the "getExercisteStats" method ?

Comment: getExerciseStats is supposed to retrieve from the exercise_stats table the last workout stats--# of reps done as in the example above. It's a foreign key in the main table that accesses exercise_stats. See the example I just posted.  As I explained, there are several exercises, and after the first one is done and committed to the db, it makes the rest of the fields null, then getExerciseStats returns null fields as a result instead of their last actual stats. – BILL WAGNER 7 mins ago   edit

Comment: Ultimately, I am trying to avoid having to make a table for each exercise, but it may be my only option. Every exercise would have to have their own table, if there is no way to prevent null being entered in blank fields.

Comment: Aah, so when a user tries to update a "current" day, with only one of the excersises filled in, the other, possibly filled in columns/excersises are made null ?

Comment: The others yes are made null as they are not being filled in yet. You got it exactly right.

Comment: But the other colums, not the other rows ? Cause if the rows are getting cleared, that would be very strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143902/discussion-between-arne-and-bill-wagner).

Comment: Other rows are not affected at all. It's just the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue with a dql query, returning exactly what I am looking for:

```
public function getStatsByDQL(User $user,  String $col)
{

$midNight = date_create('00:00:00')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$parameters = (array('user' => $user, 'date' => $midNight, 

));
$em2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
->getRepository('AppBundle:ExerciseStats')
    ->createQueryBuilder('g')
    ->setParameters($parameters)
    ->where('g.user = :user', 'g.timestamp < :date')
    ->select('g.'. $col)
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->join('g.user', 'user')
    ->orderBy( 'g.'. $col,'DESC')
    ->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    return $em2;
}
```